# how to reduce the quality of all images in a pdf file using PyMuPDF

Tags: python, image, pdf, compression, pymupdf

I am trying to make the maximum compression of the pdf file.

To do this, I save the open pdf file using the method `save(deflate=True, garbage=4, clean=True)`

But I also want to reduce the quality of all the images that are in the pdf file.

I read about [this](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-images.html#how-to-increase-image-resolution) from the documentation.

I wrote the following code, which goes through the pages of a pdf file and reduces the quality of the images it contains, and then saves the image locally:

```
doc = fitz.open("mypdffile.pdf")

for page in doc:
    for img in page.get_images():
        pix = page.get_pixmap(dpi=50)
        pix.save('reduced_image.png')
```

But I don't know how to immediately replace the images on the pages and save the pdf file.

Also, what other ways are there to compress the pdf better - maybe convert all photos to .jpeg?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems like your actual question is much less specific; you just need to know how to replace images in the PDF and then save the PDF with those replaced images. Since that's the part you're stuck on, I would recommend asking about that; asking about compression is not really the part you're stuck on, because you haven't even gotten that far yet.

Comment: Thank you! @Random Davis, you said "you haven't even gotten that far yet" - can you please tell me ways you know of to compress pdf with python, libraries? I also tried using pypdf but didn't get the result I wanted.

Comment: Apart from choosing proper `doc.save()` options, the only fruitful way to reduce file sizes is giving up the "lossless" thought and reduce image quality one way or another. This reaches from a radical removal of all images, over conversion to grayscale to image resolution reduction. Your code snippet has nothing to do with any of these alternatives. Please have a look at [this](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/tree/master/examples/replace-image) repo folder. Ping me there if questions remain.

Comment: @Mikhailo I don't know of specific ways; I was just pointing out that saving and compressing the images are two different things, and you're asking about compression in the title when your main question seems to be about saving, that's all.